# Java \ Hibernate \ ManyToOne \ Ordering

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql

I have some problems with Hibernate (JPA), PostgreSQL and ordering.

For example, we have two tables (mapped to entities):

```
- Pets (id (id), PetTypes (types_id), description (description))

- PetTypes (id (id), name (name))
```

type_id field is not required (constraint to pet_types table).

For example, we have 10 lines at pets table (at 1, 2 and 3 lines type_id is null). I need to order pets table by pet_types.name using HQL or JPA criteria (but i think its not supported by JPA).

Problem: values from pets table are not selecting with ordering if type_id is null.
I can try to use next solutions:

> 1. FROM Pets pets ORDER BY pets.petTypes.name ASC NULLS LAST
> 2. FROM Pets pets ORDER BY CASE WHEN pets.petTypes IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END, ORDER BY pets.petTypes.name ASC NULLS LAST
> 3. FROM Pets pets ORDER BY CASE WHEN pets.petTypes.name IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END, ORDER BY pets.petTypes.name ASC NULLS LAST
> 4. FROM Pets pets LEFT JOIN pets.petTypes ORDER BY pets.petTypes.name ASC NULLS LAST
> 5. FROM Pets pets ORDER BY pets.petTypes ASC NULLS LAST, pets.petTypes.names ASC
> 6. FROM Pets pets ORDER BY CASE WHEN pets.petTypes IS NULL OR pets.petTypes.name IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END, ORDER BY pets.petTypes.name ASC

But nothing works. After selecting we have 7 instead of 10 rows. Any ideas?
I can't use `UNION` statement via HQL. It's open Hibernate [bug](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-1050) since 2005.

**EDIT**

Thx to [Rodrigo Menezes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1255493/rodrigo-menezes). This solution is works:

`select p from Pets p 
left join p.petTypes pt 
order by case when pt is null then 0 else 1 end, pt.name`

Comment: Can it be that you need two orders (not sure).  Because "pets.petTypes" is null, not pets.petTypes.name or?  something like ORDER BY pets.petTypes ASC NULLS LAST,  pets.petTypes.names ASC

Comment: Yes, I tried to use this method. Nothing works. I update question above.

Comment: The sort order should have no impact on the number of rows.  Can you post the raw SQL dump?

Comment: Hibernate generate `CROSS JOIN` statement for Pets and PetTypes tables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe your HQL is generating inner or cross join.

You can force left join:

```
select p from Pets p 
left join p.petTypes pt 
order by case when pt is null then 0 else 1 end, pt.name
```

I made a case test and worked:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();

    session.beginTransaction();

    PetTypes dog = new PetTypes();
    dog.setName("Dog");
    dog.setId(1);
    PetTypes cat = new PetTypes();
    cat.setName("Cat");
    cat.setId(2);

    session.save(dog);
    session.save(cat);

    int id = 1;
    Pets joe = new Pets();
    joe.setId(id++);
    joe.setDescription("Joe");

    Pets x = new Pets();
    x.setId(id++);
    x.setDescription("Sarah");    
    x.setPetTypes(dog);

    Pets y = new Pets();
    y.setId(id++);
    y.setDescription("Jakob");    
    y.setPetTypes(cat);  

    Pets z = new Pets();
    z.setId(id++);
    z.setDescription("Xena");    
    z.setPetTypes(cat);                

    session.save(joe);
    session.save(x);
    session.save(y);
    session.save(z);

    session.getTransaction().commit();

    Query q = session.createQuery("select p from Pets p "
            + "left join p.petTypes pt "
            + "order by case when pt is null then 0 else 1 end, pt.name ");

    List<Pets> resultList = q.list();
    System.out.println("num of employess:" + resultList.size());
    for (Pets next : resultList) {
        System.out.println("pet " + next);
    }
}
```

Result:

```
num of pets:4 
pet Pets [description=Joe, petTypes=null] 
pet Pets [description=Jakob, petTypes=PetTypes [name=Cat]] 
pet Pets [description=Xena, petTypes=PetTypes [name=Cat]] 
pet Pets [description=Sarah, petTypes=PetTypes [name=Dog]]
```